# How to make a div with a circular shape?

Tags: css, css-shapes

i want to create a div with background color red and completely circular in shape

How can i do that?

Css or jquery both can be used

Answer (score 28):

You can do following

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hdokedhb/)**

```
<div id="circle"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

Other shape **[SOURCE](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)**

Comment: using border-radius value in pixels to make a circle is not a good way.. Use border-radius:50% instead

Answer (score 7):

By using a border-radius of 50% you can make a circle.
Here is an example:

CSS:

```
#exampleCircle{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id = "exampleCircle"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/j1s3koxf/1/)**

css

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: red;
}
```

html

```
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

HTML [`div`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) elements, unlike SVG [`circle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle) primitives, are always rectangular.

You could use round corners (i.e. CSS [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)) to make it look round. On square elements, a value of 50% naturally forms a circle. Use this, or even a SVG inside your HTML:

```js
document.body.innerHTML+='<i></i>'.repeat(4);
```

```css
i{border-radius:50%;display:inline-block;background:#F48024;}
svg {fill:#F48024;width:60px;height:60px;}
i:nth-of-type(1n){width:30px;height:30px;}
i:nth-of-type(2n){width:60px;height:60px;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="60"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a border-radius property of 50%.

So for example:

```
.example-div {

    border-radius: 50%

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: red;
}

<div class="circle"></div>
```

see this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bumbumpaw/rtpjfe7e/1/)